# random numbers adding to a total

Tags: java, generator

Hi everyone im getting a bit stuck with this code. i have got it all down pat except i want the random numbers to add up to the user defined amount. for example the user input 23500 i want all the random numbers to add up to the total. 
this is what i have so far

```
package containerweights;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Containerweightgenerator {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf ("%n ***Random Number Genreator*** %n%n");
        System.out.print("Enter total: ");
        double total_weight = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter amount: ");
        double total_pallets = input.nextDouble();

        double average_weight = total_weight / total_pallets;
        System.out.printf("%-40s -%10.2f%n", "Average Weight is: ", average_weight);

        double first_weight = average_weight - 50;
        double second_weight = average_weight + 50;

        double START = first_weight;
        double END = second_weight;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= total_pallets; ++idx)
        {
            showRandomInteger(START, END, random);
        }
        }
    private static void showRandomInteger(double sTART, double eND, Random aRandom) throws Exception{
        if ( sTART > eND )
        {
            throw new Exception(" Start connot exceed End.");
        }
        long range = (long)eND - (long)sTART + 1;

        long fraction = (long)(range * aRandom.nextDouble());
        int randomNumber = (int)(fraction + sTART);
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
    } 
        private static void log(String aMessage)
        {
            log(aMessage);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: what happens?... i.e. what's wrong?

Comment: So the *defined amount* is the  `total_weight` you want to reach by adding up random numbers, until you reach `total_pallets` ? What would happen if the `for`loop reaches `total_pallets` before the *defined amount*  is reached, or are they not related?

Comment: Which of the following are requirements: 1) The sum of pallet weights must be exactly W. 2) Must use exactly N pallets. 3) Each pallet weight must be in the range: [W/N-50,W/N+50]?

Comment: @LefterisE - also ask whether having each number be `random` is a real requirement.

Answer (score 4):

just give out random numbers. if the last number you give exceeds the total, instead of that number return the difference from the total

With the new requirements I edit my answer to the following:

```
int pallets=10;
int targetWeight=100;
int totalSoFar = 0;
int[] palletWeight = new int[pallets];

//Give random weight to N-1 pallets
for (int i=0; i<pallets-1; ++i){
    palletWeight[i] = random.nextInt(1.33 * targetWeight / pallets);
    totalSoFar += palletWeight[i];
}

//Check if we exceeded our target
if (totalSoFar > targetWeight){    
    while(totalSoFar > targetWeight){
      int x = random.nextInt(pallets - 1); //pick a pallet at random
      int a = random.nextInt(palletWeight[x]);
      palletWeight[x] -= a; //take of a random 'a' grams out of its weight
      totalSoFar -= a;
    }
}
//Now we are under the target weight, let the last pallet be the difference
 palletWeight[pallets-1] = targetWeight - totalSoFar;
```

Comment: Yeah. Its not necessary the final "random number" be system generated , it can be calculated ;) Gud thinkin der.

Comment: I need the program to print random numbers to the amount of total_pallets. and those numbers have to add up to total_weight.

Answer (score 1):

In case Lefteris's answer doesn't work for you (because perhaps the requirement is that all the values actually be "random" - setting aside what that means), your only choice would be to repeatedly generate sets of random numbers and summing them up.

That's ugly and slow, and I prefer Lefteris's answer.  But his does mean that the last number in the series won't be random, and its size distribution might make it stand out.